# Are there any websites providing free news, weather, photos APIs for using this data commercially

Tags: api, screen-scraping, twitter, weather-api, feed

I want to build a service which needs to get this data from some source for further analysis. Does Google, Yahoo or someone else provides free access to this data for use in other websites using some API. I think Twitter does something like this for their data although they enforce some limits on this. The data I need is mostly for US and Canada.

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a bunch of free web services here: http://www.webservicex.net/

If you can stand the ads, you can also check here: http://www.webservicelist.com/